# Gradle remembers old source code

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to create gradle custom task. The problem is that sometimes when I change something in source code, gradle shows error that in my code is error with that non existing code. For example I've created local variable `timestamp` and compiled project. Everything worked fine. But later I changed that variable to `final ... TIMESTAMP`. After that change gradle shows me error `Could not find property 'timestamp'...`. How to solve this problem? I assume that gradle has got cache?

Code

```
class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    private final String TIMESTAMP = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()

    public MyCustomTask() {
    }

    @TaskAction
    def build() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Exception

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':customer'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.ja
va:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:465)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:76)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.ja
va:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInstantiationException: Could not create task of type 'MyCustomTask'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.injectIntoNewInstance(AbstractTask.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.createTaskObject(TaskFactory.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.createTask(TaskFactory.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.createTask(AnnotationProcessingTaskF
actory.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.createTask(DependencyAutoWireTaskFacto
ry.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.task(AbstractProject.java:908)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:83)
        at build_1i1akohldagki7rlpcas5oct58.run(C:\workspace-eclipse-juno\Is2k8\customer\build.gradle:19)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.ja
va:52)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'timestamp' on task ':customer:is2k8Test'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:94)
        at pl.ydp.gradle.MyCustomTask_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at pl.ydp.gradle.MyCustomTask.<init>(MyCustomTask.groovy:15)
        at pl.ydp.gradle.MyCustomTask_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:113)
        ... 44 more
```

At the end you will find `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'timestamp' on task ':customer:is2k8Test'.`

Comment: Show us the exact and complete compilation error message, as well as the source code it refers to.

Comment: Where did you put the task class? How are you using it? Which Gradle version are you using?